# display partial results from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a sql query that pulls all types of data from 3 different tables that I now want to display in an array. I can get it to output all the data from the sql query, but I only want to display part of the array at a time based on if the value of the column in table is the same. Will try to demonstrate below.

My sql result looks like this:

```
Client  |  Order  |  Exc1  |  Exc2  |  Rest  |  Reps  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Steve   |  1A     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Mike    |  1A     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Jax     |  1A     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Steve   |  1B     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Mike    |  1B     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Jax     |  1B     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
```

I want my array to output this on a page1

```
Steve   |  1A     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Mike    |  1A     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Jax     |  1A     | this   |  That  |  This  |  that  |
```

And this on page 2 and so on. Each page will contain a list of all clients and only one order value per page. The order column value will vary for each user as they will be able to input there own text for the order field. Is this possible and if so how is the best way possible?

@Gordon Linoff here is my current query. I dont really understand what you wrote or more of how it would relate to my query. below id my current query. I did not finish outputting into array. I just have this as I was testing until I got the results I wanted.

```
function get_workout_class(){
$workout_class = array();

$workout_query = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM `movements`
LEFT JOIN  `classes` 
ON `movements`.`class_id` = `classes`.`class_id`
LEFT JOIN `clients`
ON `movements`.`class_id` = `clients`.`class_id`
WHERE `classes`.`class_id` = '$class_id' AND `user_id` = ".$_session['user_id']."
ORDER BY `movements`.`order`, `clients`.`first_name`

");
```

}

Here is a screen shot of my query result so you can see how I want them grouped. Pages to be split by different "order" values. The number of clients will vary from class to class.

http://custommovement.com/help/query.png

Here is my new query. The first part works just fine but the subquery is giving my problems. Its not pulling any results. @GordonLinoff

```
function get_workout_class($class_id){
$class_id = (int)$class_id;

$workout_class = array();

$workout_query = mysql_query("
WITH `workouts` as (
SELECT  
 `movements`.`movement_id`,
 `movements`.`order`,  
 `movements`.`mv_00`,  
 `movements`.`mv_01`,  
 `movements`.`mv_02`,  
 `movements`.`mv_03`,  
 `movements`.`mv_04`,
 `movements`.`rep_set_sec`,
 `movements`.`rest`, 
 `classes`.`class_name`,
 `clients`.`client_id`,
 `clients`.`first_name`, 
 `clients`.`last_name`, 
 `clients`.`nickname` 
 FROM  `movements` 
 LEFT JOIN  `classes` ON  `movements`.`class_id` =  `classes`.`class_id` 
 LEFT JOIN  `clients` ON  `movements`.`class_id` =  `clients`.`class_id` 
 WHERE  `classes`.`class_id` = '$class_id'
)

SELECT `wo`.* 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `order`) FROM `workouts` `wo2` WHERE `wo2`.`order` <= `wo`.`order`) as `pagenum`
FROM `workouts` `wo`
ORDER BY `pagenum`

");

echo mysql_num_rows($workout_query); 
}
```

Comment: search the site for "pagination"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem by adding a page number to your query.  Unfortunately, this is moderately painful in mysql, because you have to use a self join or correlated subquery.

Here is an example of how to do it with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct order) from t t2 where t2.order <= t.order) as pagenum
from t
order by pagenum
```

Based on your original query (but without putting it into a string):

```
with workouts as (
     SELECT *
     FROM `movements` LEFT JOIN
          `classes`
           ON `movements`.`class_id` = `classes`.`class_id` LEFT JOIN
           `clients`
          ON `movements`.`class_id` = `clients`.`class_id`
      WHERE `classes`.`class_id` = '$class_id' AND `user_id` = ".$_session['user_id']." 
    )
select wo.*,
       (select count(distinct order) from workouts wo2 where wo2.order <= wo.order) as pagenum
from workouts wo
order by pagenum
```

This will almost work . . . just one caveat.  You can put the "SELECT *" into the with clause because you have multiple columns with the same name.  Put in the columns you need.

I forget that mysql does not support the "with" statement.  My apologies for the bad syntax.  One work around is to use a view or temporary table.  Otherwise, the query is a bit more complicated because the logic has to be repeated twice:

```
select wo.*,
       (select count(distinct order)
        from (SELECT *
              FROM `movements` LEFT JOIN
                   `classes`
                   ON `movements`.`class_id` = `classes`.`class_id` LEFT JOIN
                   `clients`
                   ON `movements`.`class_id` = `clients`.`class_id`
              WHERE `classes`.`class_id` = '$class_id' AND `user_id` = ".$_session['user_id']." 
             ) wo2
        where wo2.order <= wo.order
       ) as pagenum
from (SELECT *
      FROM `movements` LEFT JOIN
           `classes`
            ON `movements`.`class_id` = `classes`.`class_id` LEFT JOIN
            `clients`
           ON `movements`.`class_id` = `clients`.`class_id`
       WHERE `classes`.`class_id` = '$class_id' AND `user_id` = ".$_session['user_id']." 
      ) wo
order by pagenum
```

Comment: I posted my query above along with a link to a screen shot of the query results as I can not figure out how your query would translate to my current query.

Comment: My understanding is that you want to break things apart by pages.  So, this query adds a "pagenum" column into the return set.  You can then choose whichever page of data you want.  To make this work with your query, just put a "with t as (<your query>)" before this.

Comment: So what you have written above would follow my existing query I posted originally?

Comment: Yes.  When I wrote the answer, you hadn't included the query.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but what do **t** and **t2** represent? in this query?

Comment: "t" is just an arbitrary name for table.  Easy to type.  t2 is an alias.  When using a correlated subquery, you need to have a different name for the table in the subquery and in the outer query.

Comment: So **t** and **t2** both need to be different tables names than what I am already using in my original query?

Comment: My latest query is posted about and I can not get the subquery to return any results. Any thoughts? @GordonLinoff

Comment: There is a comma in the from clause "FROM `workouts`, `wo`".  The query is looking for a table called wo, instead of assigning wo as an alias.

Comment: OK I removed the coma there as well as `FROM workouts wo2` and also added back ticks to `pagenum` still showing not results.

Comment: I have posted the entire query above along with the code where I am trying to echo back whether I am returning any results or not. Question, do I need to create the tables `wo` and `wo2` in order for this to work? Without being able to run this script in phpMyadmin and see what results are being returned Im kind  of at a loss as far as what to change/debug.

Comment: Does mysql support the "WITH" clause?

Comment: No.  It was my bad.  I thought all common databases supported WITH, and I was wrong.

Comment: I just saw that you edited the query yesterday without the `WITH`. It works perfect...Thank you so much!

Comment: Gordon, is there a way to do a `SELECT MAX(pagenum) as lastpage` so I can tell php when I have reached the end of the class?

Answer (score 1):

try this. It uses subquery for the max value of the order.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    myTable a INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  Client, 
                        Max(`Order`) as MaxOrder
                FROM    myTable
                GROUP BY Client
            ) c
                ON a.Client = c.Client AND
                   a.`Order` = c.MaxOrder
```

or the simpliest if i'm not mistaken

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  `Order` = '1B'
```

Comment: I can get the exact value from the table but I want all the results to be returned where the clients are in the class and display all data associated with that class. I only want to display one order value at a time. I think pagination may be my answer but not certain yet.

Comment: oh yes, so you want to display results partially. go for `pagination` :)

Comment: One thing where pagination my not work. When my query is returned the number of pages needed to display all my data will vary by the number of different "order" values. For example in class I may have 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D (4pages) and another class would possibly be 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E (5pages). Would pagination still be a possibility?